# How to check if a string exists within an array in PHP?

Tags: php

So I have an array of acceptable animals:

```
$animals = array('tiger','lion','dog');
```

How can I see if the animal submitted by the user:

```
$userSubmittedAnimal = clean($_POST['animal']);
```

matches one of the 3 acceptable ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[in_array](https://www.php.net/in_array) — Checks if a value exists in an array

```
$animals = array('tiger','lion','dog');
$userSubmittedAnimal = clean($_POST['animal']);

if (in_array($userSubmittedAnimal, $animals )) {
    echo "It's in the array";
}
```

Comment: How about if the user typed: tige ? is there a partial search ?